# giving fideIn fadeOut effect on changing the image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working with responsive web design and I wanted to slide some images in to a page. I tried some plugins but the problem with the plugin is it uses width and height property and also assigns `position: absolute`. So I thought of changing the `src` of the image myself using js and it worked fine, but can I give some transition effect to it?

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/an7Fd/)

What I have done is:

```
var i = 0;
var total = 2;
window.setInterval(function() {
    show_hide();
}, 1000);

function show_hide() {
    var img = $('.image-holder img, .image-holder2 img');
    //alert(img.length);
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        img[0].src = 'http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png';
        img[1].src = 'http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png';
        i = 0;
    }
    else {
        img[0].src = 'http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834';
        img[1].src = 'http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834';
    }
    i++;
}
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div  class="image-holder" >
    <img src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834"  />
</div>
<div  class="image-holder2" >
    <img src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834"  />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to do a cross fade or a fade to 'black' and then show the other picture?

Comment: a there should be an effect in transition from one to other..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I put together. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/fpp5d/)

javascript

```
var img = $(".image-holder img")
var i = 0;
var count = img.length - 1;

setInterval(function() {
    showImage(i);
    i++;
    if (i > count) i = 0;
}, 2000);

function showImage(i) {
    img.eq(i - 1).animate({
        "opacity": "0"
    }, 1000);
    img.eq(i).animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, 1000);
}​
```

HTML

```
<div  class="image-holder" >
<img src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834"  />


</div>
<div  class="image-holder" >
<img src="http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png"  />
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.image-holder img{ opacity: 0;}
.image-holder { position: absolute; }
```